# Custom border around uitextview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to make a customized border around a `UITextview` that contains characters instead of the default border options. Any pointer on how to accomplish this?

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.  I'm sure that I can probably do this with a label by putting it over a UITextview, but I wanted to at least ask and see if anyone knew how to do this with a customized border.

[image]

Comment: Any reference image/example would be good to understand your scenario.

Comment: some more infos could lead to a (better) answer...

Comment: can you explain what you want, I think this qustion is not clear, can you show some screen shots?

Comment: you want to add rounded text around UITextView?

Comment: I updated my question.  Hopefully this will help out a bit.

Comment: I don't think you can do it using a simple UITextView, you need to build your own UIView subclass composed by different pieces, at least an image view and a textview.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, you need a image(texted border) with all your need to the `UItextView` border :

then try something like this :

```
[self.txtView.layer setBorderWidth:3.0];
[self.txtView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"textedImage.png"]] CGColor]];
```

Comment: Don't forget to add #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Answer (score 0):

USe this code.

```
txtfld.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];

txtfld.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
```

and remember to `import #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your .h file

You can also specify your RGB value.

```
txtfld.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:178.0f/255.0f green:178.0f/255.0f blue:178.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] CGColor];
```

Comment: Please read the question again. This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: sorry rmmaddy i think op want default border...i think for this he has to create textview inside the uiview